# How to find files with specific case-insensitive extension names in Python

Tags: python, file, find, case-insensitive

`glob.glob()` is case-sensitive.
Is there any simple way to find files with specific case-insensitive extension names in Python.

Comment: `[f for f in glob.glob(f"{sql_path}/*.[sS][qQ][lL]")]` - List of all combinations `sql` with the path to the file in one line of code.

Answer (score 13):

The [*fnmatch*](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/fnmatch.html#module-fnmatch) module provides more control over pattern matching than the *glob* module:

```
>>> import os
>>> from fnmatch import filter
>>> filter(os.listdir('.'), '*.[Pp][Yy]')
```

You can also use [*os.listdir()*](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/os.html#os.listdir) followed by a regular expression match:

```
>>> import os, re
>>> [filename for filename in os.listdir('.') 
              if re.search(r'\.py$', filename, re.IGNORECASE)]
```

Comment: What if the Host OS is not case-insensitive?

Comment: @Abhijit Do a case-insensitive search to find the actual filenames and then use the actual filenames with their original case.

Answer (score 6):

This should do the trick:

```
import os
import glob

def find_case_insensitve(dirname, extensions):
    for filename in glob.glob(dirname):
        base, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
        if ext.lower() in extensions:
            print filename


find_case_insensitve('/home/anthon/Desktop/*', ['.jpeg', '.png', '.jpg'])
```

Don't forget to specify the list of extensions in lowercase.